# "error: variable keyboard is already defined in method main(String [])"

Tags: java, string, variables, keyboard

I'm getting several error messages when I try to run my program, the main one which bothers me being "error: variable keyboard is already defined in method main(String [])"

Am I supposed to but main(String []) more than once in my program, or just in the beginning as I have it? What else could be wrong here?

Here is the beginning of my program:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    String firstName, lastName;
    int moviesDownloaded, stateResidency;
    double movieCost, netPayment, tax, discount, totalCharge, payment, taxRate;

    System.out.println("Enter your first name:");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    firstName = keyboard.nextString();

    System.out.println("Enter your last name:");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    lastName = keyboard.nextString();

    System.out.println("Enter the number of movies downloaded:");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    moviesDownloaded = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the cost per movie:");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    movieCost = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Indicate your state of residency. Enter 1 for Mississippi or 2 for any other state.");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    stateResidency = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 4):

You should only declare and initialize keyboard once and then use it. So remove all lines of the type: `Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);` apart from the first one. 
Otherwise you try to declare the same variable multiple times and thus java complains.

Comment: @AlvinWong `keyboard` is a variable of type `Scanner`. I really do not understand what are you trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this has been long solved by this point but I came across it and I really like closure, because Ivaylo Strandjev answer was not chosen. Also in case anyone else stumbles across this.

The error is saying you defined the variable keyboard in this scope already and you are trying to define it again.
like Ivaylo Strandjev was saying.
You can try the following:

1 remove the declaration portion

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
String firstName, lastName;
int moviesDownloaded, stateResidency;
double movieCost, netPayment, tax, discount, totalCharge, payment, taxRate;

System.out.println("Enter your first name:");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
firstName = keyboard.nextString();

System.out.println("Enter your last name:");
keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); //-----changed
lastName = keyboard.nextString();

System.out.println("Enter the number of movies downloaded:");
keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); //-----changed
moviesDownloaded = keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter the cost per movie:");
keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);//-----changed
movieCost = keyboard.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Indicate your state of residency. Enter 1 for Mississippi or 2 for any other state.");
keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);//-----changed
stateResidency = keyboard.nextInt();`
```

or this, change the new variable names

```
public static void main(String[]args){
String firstName, lastName;
int moviesDownloaded, stateResidency;
double movieCost, netPayment, tax, discount, totalCharge, payment, taxRate;

System.out.println("Enter your first name:");
Scanner keyboard1 = new Scanner(System.in);
firstName = keyboard1.nextString();

System.out.println("Enter your last name:");
Scanner keyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in);//-----changed
lastName = keyboard2.nextString();

System.out.println("Enter the number of movies downloaded:");
Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);//-----changed
moviesDownloaded = keyboard3.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter the cost per movie:");
Scanner keyboard4 = new Scanner(System.in);//-----changed
movieCost = keyboard4.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Indicate your state of residency. Enter 1 for Mississippi or 2 for any other state.");
Scanner keyboard5 = new Scanner(System.in);//-----changed
stateResidency = keyboard5.nextInt();`
```

Comment: What is the point in keeping `keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);` in your code? You only need one `keyboard` and you don't need to create new scanners for each new user input request.

Comment: you're absolutely right tom I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote this. I think I only wrote this looking at the error and did not think about the actual functionality of the code

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to initialize Keyboard every time you use it. You can declare it once at the top of the program, and just call keyboard.next() each time you want to get something from it.